# Why is session[:user_id] is empty after sign up with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, session, devise

This is how my OmniauthCallbacksController looks like. I set the session[:user_id] for FB sign in here and it works fine.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      line #9  
      sign_in_and_redirect @user , :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception



  # uncomment this block if I want to set session after a sign up through devise.
  # def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  #   session[:user_id] = resource.id
  # end



def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

end

The problem is when I uncomment the code block above, sign ups work for devise, but I get the following error when I try to sign up through Facebook, I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_model' for 2:Fixnum):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `facebook'
```

How do I make the two work together?

Answer (score 0):

`after_sign_in_path_for` should return an url or a resource

`sign_in_and_redirect` will use that url/resource to redirect the page

we can update that method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:user_id] = resource.id
  root_path
end
```

Comment: I just solved the problem by removing the current_user method I defined explicitly. I think since omniauth was configured inside devise.rb, I should not have to defined currenta_user. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: yes, devise defined `current_user` already. I just comment about using `after_sign_in_path_for` in case you need it :)